# Show button when parent cursor in parent control

Tags: c#, .net

For my combo boxes in my application, I want to allow the user to edit the collection that the controls are bound to. To do this, I want to have a button that appears when the cursor is over the control. So, I created a user control with a combo box and a button on it. However, I am having an issue getting the button to show at the right times. Here is my code:

```
public partial class CollectionDropDown : UserControl
    {
        public CollectionDropDown()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetEventsRecursively(Controls);
        }

        public void SetEventsRecursively(ControlCollection controls)
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in controls)
            {
                ctrl.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(ctrl_MouseLeave);
                ctrl.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(ctrl_MouseEnter);
                SetEventsRecursively(ctrl.Controls);
            }
        }

        void ctrl_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Visible = true;
        }

        void ctrl_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

So the idea was that all of the controls would have the same mouse enters/leaves so when the mouse enters the whole of the control the button would be visible and when it leaves it would be invisible. The problem is the mouse leave event fires before the enter. Therefore, when you move the mouse into the control, the button becomes visible. But when you try to move to the button, whatever control the cursor was over fires the mouse leave and the button becomes invisible before you "enter" it. Any thoughts?

Comment: why not add some logic to know if the mouse is actually in the control?

Comment: At least one reason it doesn't work right is because you forgot about the enter/leave events for the control itself.  The blinking button isn't that pretty, the better way to do it is by only using the Enter event and then starting a 200 msec timer that checks if the mouse is no longer over the control.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I do have that event hooked up for the parent as well, it's just done through the designer. I like the timer idea though.

Comment: I would say, provide a member variable to "remember", which control has mouse. And in MouseEnter/MouseLeave don't do anything unless this is the control you've cached. If it is, reset the variable. I don't like timer idea in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used emd's suggestion to check if the mouse was in the bounds of the control in the mouse leave event.

```
if (!this.RectangleToScreen(ClientRectangle).Contains(Cursor.Position))
                button1.Visible = false;
```

That produced the result I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I am not sure if syntax is right

```
    Control ctrl = null;
    void ctrl_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        If (ctrl == null) 
        {
           button1.Visible = true;
           ctrl = sender; 
        }
    }

    void ctrl_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        If (ctrl != null && ctrl.Equals(sender)) 
        {
           button1.Visible = false;
           ctrl = null; 
        }
    }
```